# Atomic weapon design book

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aerospace-engineering, nuclear-engineering

I’m starting my degree in nuclear engineering in September and was wondering if anyone knew any good books for Atomic Weapon design please?

Comment: Energy and mass are things that matter.  When you employ these to disrupt things people need, they become weapons. All physics books are also good books for "Atomic Weapon design" after all a club is made of atoms too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's resource hunting and that's not the purpose of the site. See the [Help] section.

Comment: keep your homeland security investigations to yourself.

Comment: also, I hope you're not expecting to learn bombs in that major because you won't

Comment: There's always *The Plutonium Handbook* for those sleepless nights ;) https://www.amazon.com/Plutonium-Handbook-Guide-Technology-Volumes/dp/B004XWN60M Pro tip, it's not a great book to take on a plane - Kinda freaks TSA out.

Comment: Some other gen ref - *The Islamic Bomb* by Weissman and Krosney, *The Decision to Use The Atomic Bomb and the Engineering of an American Myth* by Gar Alperovitz. *The Making of the Atomic Bomb* by Richard Rhodes. There's an excellent one on Sakharov's first Soviet bomb build, but I've forgotten the name of it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sounds like we'd be helping Mr. Ayatollah

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the *Los Alamos Primer*, by Richard Serber.